# Templates Non Type Parameters+ Lvalue/Rvalue

Tags: c++, templates, lvalue, rvalue

> C++03 $14.1/6 - "A non-type
>   non-reference template-parameter is
>   not an lvalue."
>
> C++0x $14.2/6- "A non-type
>   non-reference template-parameter is an
>   rvalue."

Is there any specific rationale behind rewording it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the new C++0x wording, an expression can either be an *lvalue*, *xvalue* or *prvalue*. The first two are summed as *glvalue* and the latter two as *rvalue*.

The C++0x text says **prvalue**, not **rvalue**. Since neither *"not lvalue"* nor *"rvalue"* will say definitely what it is.

Comment: Oh. I just downloaded N3126 and found it. I was working with N3000 uptil now :(